# Fetched Property in XCode Data Model Editor for minimum value

Tags: cocoa, xcode, core-data, minimum, fetched-property

How do I add a Fetched Property in XCode's Data Model Editor for minimum value of one attribute??

My model:

[Model http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b48853070e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b48853070e.png)

```
Item (name, note, storedItem)
StoredItem (price, item)
Item 1 ---> N StoredITem (1->N Relationship)
```

I want that Item has a fetched property named minPrice and its value is the minimum value setted for price in the storedItems.

Example:

```
Item1 (banana, storedItem1 ... storedItem4, 10)
StoredItem1 (10,item1)
StoredItem2 (15,item1)
StoredItem3 (30,item1)
StoredItem4 (54,item1)
```

What do I put in Destination?? StoredItem?

[Fetched Property in Data Model Editor http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2a68de007d.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2a68de007d.png)

And what do I put in Expression??

[Expression in Data Model Editor http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/766ab9af6f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/766ab9af6f.png)

Answer (score 2):

The destination is the type of entity you want back.

It sounds like you want a StoredItem back, since that has a price on it.

What I think you want is a fetched property on Item called minPrice, with this expression:

```
"@min.storedItems.price"
```