# How can I created a fetched property to get the entity with a minimum field?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fetched-property

I can't solve this problem... I'm having some problems with fetched properties (not with fetched requests).

How can I created a fetched property to get the entity with a minimum field?
If you see these captures, you will see it:
[image]
[image]

What I have to write in fetched property called minItemTimestamp?
I tried several options but don't work.
"@min.items.timestamp"
"items.@min.timestamp"
@min seems it is an aggregate and not sure that is what I'm looking for.

I tried this reply, but no luck:
[Fetched Property in XCode Data Model Editor for minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664776/fetched-property-in-xcode-data-model-editor-for-minimum-value)

So, can I create a fetched property to get from all items that belong to current category, the one with minimum timestamp?

Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a fetched property.

use the following lines of code:

```
id minTimestamp=[myCategory.items valueForKeyPath:@"@min.timestamp"];
id maxTimestamp=[myCategory.items valueForKeyPath:@"@max.timestamp"];
```

see [using a @min in predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023017/using-a-min-in-predicate)

Answer (score 0):

The NSFetchedResultsController will accept an array of NSSortDescriptors via a property and will sort the data for you accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand it. Can you explain it in a different way, please?

Comment: Sorry. I fixed that part accessing the relationship. Something like items.count.